# regex.test is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso aplicar uma máscara que formata tanto celular fixo quanto telefone.

Tentei:

```
<input [pattern]="customPatterns" type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero" [(ngModel)]="empresa.numero">
```

e no componente:

```
  public customPatterns = { pattern: new RegExp(/^(?:(?:\+|00)?(55)\s?)?(?:\(?([1-9][0-9])\)?\s?)?(?:((?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3})\-?(\d{4}))$/)};
```

Porém eu recebo:

> RROR TypeError: regex.test is not a function

Answer (score -1):

Está usando ngmask?
 Acredito que seja necessário informar os parametros:

code    meaning
0   digits (like 0 to 9 numbers)
9   digits (like 0 to 9 numbers), but optional
A   letters (uppercase or lowercase) and digits
S   only letters (uppercase or lowercase)

---

Tente:

public customPatterns = {'A': { pattern: new RegExp(/^(?:(?:+|00)?(55)\s?)?(?:(?([1-9][0-9]))?\s?)?(?:((?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3})-?(\d{4}))$/)}};

Comment: Há uma mistura de inglês com português em sua resposta ou é impressão minha?

Comment: É um trecho da documentação da lib ngx-mask

Comment: Mas caso não esteja, tente remover o objeto do customPatterns:

public customPatterns = new RegExp(/^(?:(?:\+|00)?(55)\s?)?(?:\(?([1-9][0-9])\)?\s?)?(?:((?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3})\-?(\d{4}))$/);